# What is the equivalent Java configuration for an XML p-namespace attribute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

For example., how can I convert the following to a JavaConfig `@Bean`?

```
<bean id="ldapDao" class="org.mycompany.LdapDAOImpl" p:ldapUrl-ref="ldapHost"/>
```

Here's where I'm at with the equivalent JavaConfig Bean

```
@Bean(name="ldapDao")
public LdapDAOImpl getLdapDAOImpl(){
    LdapDAOImpl ldapDAOImpl = new LdapDAOImpl();
    //How can I set the reference here to ldapHost?
    return new LdapDAOImpl();
}
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Are you confused about what `p:ldapUrl-ref` is?

Comment: I've updated the question. Let me know if it's not clear yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the [`p-namespace`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-p-namespace) is defined as

> The `p-namespace` enables you to use the bean element’s attributes,
>   instead of nested `<property/>` elements, to describe your property
>   values and/or collaborating beans.

In other words, it's just an alternative for defining bean properties.

For example,

```
<bean id="ldapDao" class="org.mycompany.LdapDAOImpl" p:ldapUrl-ref="ldapHost"/>
```

is equivalent to

```
<bean id="ldapDao" class="org.mycompany.LdapDAOImpl">
    <property name="ldapUrl" ref="ldapHost" />
</bean>
```

where the `-ref` suffix in the `p:` attribute is explained with an example in the documentation

> As you can see, this example includes not only a property value using
>   the p-namespace, but also uses a special format to declare property
>   references. Whereas the first bean definition uses `<property name="spouse" ref="jane"/>`to create a reference from bean john to
>   bean jane, the second bean definition uses `p:spouse-ref="jane"` as an
>   attribute to do the exact same thing. In this case spouse is the
>   property name, whereas the `-ref` part indicates that this is not a
>   straight value but rather a reference to another bean.

Each `property` element appearing in your `<bean>` definition requires a corresponding setter in the bean class.

Given all the above, the corresponding `@Bean` definition would be one that initializes an object of type `org.mycompany.LdapDAOImpl` and invokes its `setLdapUrl` setter with the object corresponding to the bean named `ldapHost` as an argument.

For example, assuming you had such a bean

```
@Bean
public LdapHost ldapHost() {
    return new LdapHost();
}
```

you'd then use that to initialize your `ldapDao`

```
@Bean
public LdapDaoImpl ldapDao() {
    LdapDaoImpl ldapDao = new LdapDaoImpl();
    ldapDao.setLdapUrl(ldapHost());
    return ldapDao;
}
```

Alternatively, you can have Spring inject it for you.

```
@Bean
public LdapDaoImpl ldapDao(LdapHost ldapHost) {
    LdapDaoImpl ldapDao = new LdapDaoImpl();
    ldapDao.setLdapUrl(ldapHost);
    return ldapDao;
}
```

Comment: I've marked your answer as the Chosen one for clearly explaining the issue. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks Like the p:ldapUrl-ref is nothing but setting the value of ldapUrl in my LdapDAOImpl class. So simple setter works just fine.

```
@Bean(name="ldapDao")
    public LdapDAOImpl getLdapDAOImpl(){
        LdapDAOImpl ldapDAOImpl = new LdapDAOImpl();
        ldapDAOImpl.setLdapUrl(url);
        return new LdapDAOImpl();
    }
```